# Android, Work manager starts service after ~2-3 minutes after killing my app

Tags: android, service, android-workmanager

I am using work manager to run my service (foreground service) even after the app is killed.
But after I kill my app, my service gets started after 2-3 minutes of killing my app. How do I make the work manager to start my service immediately after killing the app?

I'm using the following code for Work manager:

```
public class DemoSyncJob extends Worker {

    public static final String TAG = ">>>> job_demo_tag";

    public DemoSyncJob(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Worker.Result doWork() {
        // run your job here
        Log.d(TAG, "onRunJob: ");
        if(!isMyServiceRunning(getApplicationContext(), MessageReceiverService.class)){
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MessageReceiverService.class);
            getApplicationContext().startService(intent);
        }
        scheduleJob();
        return Worker.Result.success();
    }

    public static WorkRequest scheduleJob() {
        return new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(DemoSyncJob.class)
                .build();

    }

    public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context, Class<?> serviceClass) {
        try {
            ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
                if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "isMyServiceRunning: ",e );
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot control *exactly* when the work manager does what it does. That's the whole purpose of the work manager; it will start when it can, given the constrains. It's not a real time work manager.

Comment: Any alternative to Work Manager, we can have better control over?

Comment: Do you really need the service to run *immediately*? If so, you may want to consider having the service in Foreground (if it's so important to you) or (and this is a "I'm not sure if it will work"), you can try to set an "EXACT" alarm when you realize you're being destroyed. Problem is, you can't always tell when that's about to happen :/

Comment: I'm using foreground service right now. But it stops as soon as my app is killed. I used work manager to handle this. Is there any other way I can stop my foreground service from getting stopped on app kill?

Comment: I tried using 'onTaskRemoved()' callback as well to restart the service on app kill. But this callback was getting triggered  only after a few minutes of app kill - not immediately.

Comment: Yes, I cannot think of another way; the truth is, if your app is killed (by the user) like onTaskRemoved (which is not called in all instances, so you cannot really rely on that), there's not much you can do, short of scheduling exact alarms to check periodically and react to it; at least that i can think of.

Comment: If your app is killed, that's a deliberate action by the user, you cannot really prevent it. If the OS kills you, that means there's another issue: either memory constrains, or aggressive Android battery savings, but that also means your service wasn't really doing anything important (in the eyes of Android).

Comment: Ultimately, Android is a mobile operating system with limited resources and tight constraints, not a real-time embedded OS. You're sharing resources with every other app, the OS gives you tools to perform things and background jobs, but not on YOUR constraints.

Comment: "scheduling exact alarms" I am quite sure they have their own restrictions too. Something like; at least 3-5 minutes between checks otherwise, the system will temporarily or permanently block the scheduler

Comment: you worker be kill in chinese device for that you need to give auto start permission